# Timeout performing EXISTS [keyname], inst: 2, mgr: ExecuteSelect, queue: 0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0/0, in=0/0

Tags: c#, multithreading, exists, stackexchange.redis, timeoutexception

I'm using StackExchange.Redis version 1.0.0.0 in C# Windows Application. This Application is Multi-Thread and we save some values in Redis Cache.
When I need a key's value, First i check Existence of that key by `EXISTS` command.

some times an Exception occurs:

> Timeout performing EXISTS SpeedLimit_GF__VU_3, inst: 2, mgr:
>   ExecuteSelect, queue: 0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0/0, in=0/0,
>   IOCP:(Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=8,Max=1000),
>   WORKER:(Busy=1,Free=1022,Min=8,Max=1023)
>          at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message
>   message, ResultProcessor1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
>          at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
>          at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.KeyExists(RedisKey key, CommandFlags flags)
>       . . .

Cache Server and Application Server is same. What can be the reason and how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

That error message tells me that the client wasn't doing anything interesting at the time, so the question becomes: what was the *server* doing? Is there anything in `slowlog get`  that ties to this time? Is there anything ib the server log? In particular, my first thoughts would be:

1. Was the server persisting (aof rewrite or rdb) at this point?
2. Was there a long running operation blocking the server (`keys *` for example, which you shouldn't use)
3. Was it establishing replication with a master/slave?
4. Was there a network blip?

Comment: Thank you Marc. Let me check it again and monitor Redis with Slowlog get and other commands. i will share result here.

Comment: Hi Javed, Any update on this? I am getting the same exception with same parameter values: queue: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0

Comment: Hello. we change the server and upgraded it to a more powerful hardware(not only because of redis, for all other services). so we dont get this error again. i guess it was about resource. unfortunately i didn't dig deep on redis.